# For loop issues in R as a novice

Tags: r, loops, for-loop

```
N <- c(6, 11, 21)

for (t in 4:20) {
  N[t] <- round( 0.5*N[t-1] + sqrt(N[t-2]) + log10(1+N[t-3]) )
}

N
## [1] 20
```

I'm trying to print out the contents of N each time it runs in RStudio but am running into the issue of it only printing out one number (20 in this instance) instead of the the entire range of numbers. There seems to be a very simple way to fix this, but as I am very new to R and programming I'm stumped.

Comment: Are you perhaps meaning to print out `N`? If you want it to print the value of `t` each time the for loop runs you can add `print(t)` to the code inside the curly brackets and it will print each time the loop runs.

Comment: I am trying to print out the contents of N, and that being the case printing out N currently produces the same issue I originally had; the method of print (t) also does not seem to solve the issue.

Comment: You wrote `t` instead of `N`. Are you trying to see the contents of N each time the loop runs, or just the resulting value of N at the end? If it's the latter just replace the `t` at the end with `N` and you'll see the contents of `N`.

Comment: Printing t instead of N was an issue I quickly realized once you brought it up. Now I am trying to print the content of N each time the loop runs.

Comment: If you want it to print `N` each time it runs then do what I said in my first comment but replace `t` with `N`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so i think that you maybe are just trying to print N out, and not t

```
N <- c(6, 11, 21)
for (t in 4:20) {N[t] <- round( 0.5*N[t-1] + sqrt(N[t-2]) + log10(1+N[t-3]) )}
N

[1]  6 11 21 15 13 12 11 10  9  9  9  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8  8
```

Comment: That did it! What's odd is that I attempted to print out N on multiple occasions with no luck, but copy and pasting it from your comment did the trick.